# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UUID'

Tags: swift, database, swiftui, binding, supabase

I am attempting to log into my app using Supabase.

I cannot solve this error and any attempt leads to even more bugs.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

The line with the bug is if let loggedInUserId = loggedInUserId {

```
import Foundation
import Supabase

class LogInViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let supabase: SupabaseClient
    @Published var displayName: String = ""
    
    init() {
        supabase = SupabaseClient(supabaseURL: URL(string: Config.supabaseURL)!, supabaseKey: Config.supabaseKey)
    }
    
    func login(email: String, password: String, onSuccess: @escaping (String) -> Void, onError: @escaping (String) -> Void) async {
        do {
            try await supabase.auth.signIn(email: email, password: password)
            let session = try await supabase.auth.session
            let loggedInUserId = session.user.id
            if let loggedInUserId = loggedInUserId {
                let userDataAccess = UserDataAccess(supabase: supabase)
                userDataAccess.fetchUserDataByUserId(userId: loggedInUserId.uuidString) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let userData):
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.displayName = userData.displayName 
                            onSuccess(self.displayName)
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            onError("Error fetching user data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    onError("Error retrieving logged-in user's session.")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                onError("Error during login: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: seem like your `session.user.id` is `UUID`, not Optional Type, so it not suitable for `if let`. Don't use `if let` if you don't understand what it is

Comment: Fair, what is an alternative to if let i this scenario?

Comment: `if let` is useless if `session.user.id` isn't optional type, so just remove it, use session.user.id instead of loggedInUserId

Comment: fyi instead of `DispatchQueue.main.async {` you can use `Task { @MainQueue in` to keep the task cancellation chain working